# Leetcode 377. Combination Sum IV (Backtrack approach)

Tags: javascript

The [combination sum 4](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-iv/) problem is a well known coding interview problem. It states the following:

> Given an array of distinct integers nums and a target integer target, return the number of possible combinations that add up to target. You may assume that you have an infinite number of each kind of coin.

This problem can be solved optimally through dynamic programming and that is very well explained on the problem solution that leetcode provides.

**However**, this problem can also be solved recursively (*and* through backtracking). I am trying to solve this problem with backtracking to further cement my understanding of backtracking. I have solved the problem recursively with a loop, however, I don't understand why my conversion of it to using indexes instead of looping is broken. Is it not possible to solve this problem through indexing manually?

```js
// This one works
function combinationSum4 (nums, target, currTotal=[0], nbWays=[0]) {
    
    if (currTotal[0] === target) {
        nbWays[0]++;
        return nbWays[0];
    }
    
    if (currTotal[0] > target) {
        return nbWays[0];
    }

    for (const num of nums) {
        currTotal[0] += num;
        combinationSum4(nums, target, currTotal, nbWays);
        currTotal[0] -= num;
    }
    
    return nbWays[0];
}
```

Below, I want to use two indices, a "fast" index and a "slow" index. For example, if we had `nums=[1,2,3]` and a `target=4`. Then, we'd have something like:

```
               0
          i=0 /  
             /   
            1[1]   
       i=0 /     \   
         2[1,1]   \ i=1     
      i=0/         **3[1,2]**
        3[1,1,1]  /  
      /          / i=0
    ...        4[1,2,1]
```

Notice how when we get to i=1, we loop back from the beginning from 0.  I'm not really sure how to do this in code though without a loop (that's why I use `i` in this diagram). Is this not possible?

```js
// This one is broken
function combinationSum4 (nums, target, currTotal=[0], nbWays=[0], fastIndex=0, slowIndex=0) {
    
    if (currTotal[0] === target) {
        nbWays[0]++;
        return nbWays[0];
    }
    
    if (currTotal[0] > target || slowIndex >= nums.length || fastIndex >= nums.length) {
        return nbWays[0];
    }
    
    const num = nums[fastIndex];
    currTotal[0] += num;
    combinationSum4(nums, target, currTotal, nbWays, fastIndex, slowIndex);
    currTotal[0] -= num;
    combinationSum4(nums, target, currTotal, nbWays, fastIndex+1, slowIndex);

    combinationSum4(nums, target, currTotal, nbWays, 0, slowIndex+1);

    return nbWays[0];
}
```

Comment: Backtracking in this case is essentially a depth first search of a tree. The tree itself is implicit from the rules.